# What is a convex optimisation problem? Objective function convex, domain convex or codomain convex?

Tags: definition, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

My teacher in the course [Mat-2.3139](https://noppa.aalto.fi/noppa/kurssi/mat-2.3139/etusivu) did not want to answer this question because it would take too much time. So what does a convex optimisation problem actually mean? Convex objective function? Convex domain or convex codomain? Or something else?

Comment: Yes. Everything should be convex; cost and constraints. Not sure why your teacher thought that would take so long?

Comment: @copper.hat My teacher said that it is not really like that: there are things like quasiconvex and things like that which still falls under general term "convex optimization" -- I understood that it is not that black and white, I found it very confusing that he was unable to present a clear basic definition. I understood that certain problems may have only convex objective function and not convex domain/codomain and still be called convex problem -- well I don't really know, he was very vague/secretive here.

Comment: Then those problems would be quasi-convex, pueudo-convex, etc. A convex problem is a convex cost with convex constraints. **Every** minimization/maximization problem can be expressed as a linear cost (hence convex) with (possibly) non-convex constraints.

Comment: @copper.hat or does the convex optimisation problems contain all problems that have the word "convex" in it? I am not yet sure whether it is a general term for all kind of "something-convex" problems or a specific term to certain mathematical problems.

Comment: The general point of convex problems is that a local minimum is a global minimum. There are all sorts of relaxations and generalizations (or transformations as in posynomials), but generally when one says a convex problem it means everything relevant is convex. Like I wrote, every minimization problem can be written as a convex cost with non-convex constraints, so just having the word 'convex' in there does not make a problem convex. Convex problems are a big deal; Rockafellar's watershed.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not yet sure whether it is a general term for all kind of "something-convex" problems or a specific term to certain mathematical problems.

It could be both: some people, like your teacher, may decide to use it as a general term for "something-convex" in it, while others stick to a precise interpretation. I prefer the latter.

An appeal to authority: *Convex Optimization* by Boyd and Vandenberghe has $17908$ citations in Google Scholar, and says this:

[image: convex]

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is with the naming convection which has not been made concrete over the years. Most authors (and readers) seem not to highlight on the distinction between a "convex function" and a "convex problem".

A more appealing distinct convention is as follows:

A function *f* need not be defined over a convex domain for *f* to be called a convex function. This is contrary to what most authors state, in which they include the "convex domain" as a criteria for the objective function to be called a convex function.

Bearing this in mind, A convex problem is defined as an optimization of a convex function *f* defined over a convex domain *X*. If it is a constrained problem, then this also implies that a convex (constrained) problem is one in which the objective function f is convex and the constraints are convex.

You will find that this naming convection is consistently used on Wiki i.e. convex (constrained) problem is "...problem of minimizing convex functions over convex sets", see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_optimization

The confusion of the OP & (many people) stems mainly from the convention of the "convex function definition" of most authors as stated above. That being said, I do find this "new" convention appealing due to issues regarding necessary and sufficient optimality conditions of convex constrained optimization problems.