# What needs to be linear for the problem to be considered linear?

Tags: definition, linear-programming

Harry Altman presented an excellent question in a comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544839/why-nonlinear-programming-problem-nlo-called-nonlinear-what-does-nonlinear#comment1160127_544839): **What needs to be linear for the problem to be considered linear?** So is it enough to a have linear objective function or other requirements for example to the smoothness?

Comment: Same as with convex, costs and constraints are affine. I'm not sure why the term linear is so often used instead of affine, but it is pretty much ingrained by now.

Comment: Are you asking about linear programs or about some generality of "linear problems"?

Comment: @hardmath I think the first answer is about the linear problems. With linear programs you are referring to LP? Yes I tagged this under linear-programming (LP). Did I understand your question?

Comment: @hhh: I wondered if you asked about linear vs. nonlinear "programming" (the term is a little awkward), i.e. classifications of optimization problems.  If the objective function is a "linear function" (first-degree polynomial) and the constraints are linear inequalities, then an optimization problem is usually called a linear program.  Saying a problem is a "linear problem" is a sweeping description, needing more context to be precise.  For examples, a system of first-degree polynomials is called a "system of linear equations", but differential equations can also be "linear" vs. "nonlinear".

Answer (score 1):

In a linear context, you have coefficients.  In other words, you've got a module $M$ over a ring $R$.  Then we can take linear combinations, $r_1m_1+\cdots +r_nm_n$, with $r_i\in R$, $m_i\in M$.  Choosing a module, $M$, and a ring, $R$, let's you define linear in all kinds of contexts.  Maybe you want $R=\mathbb{R}$ and $M$ to be a vector space.  Then we can get systems of linear equations.  Maybe $R$ and $M$ are $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ functions of variable $x$ for $R$ and variables $x$ and $y$ for $M$.  This sets up a context for differential equations.